# Merging surefire JUnit reports

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, jira-xray

I have a Java project, which consists of loads of maven modules and a considerable amount of unit/integration tests. The project is configured to create test reports via the surefire plugin. Now this plugin basically creates an XML-report per test class and is scheduled to run once a day and executed on Jenkins.

What I want to do is, send the those XML-reports to a test management system (XRAY) in order to make them more visible and manageable. My (naive) approach would be to just just add a post build script on Jenkins and send those reports via curl to the test managements REST-API. This API offers a way to send a single report file at a time. This report file can either be single or nested, i.e. I can basically send both of the following and it works:

**Single report**

```
  <testsuite>
  ...
  </testsuite>
```

**Aggregated report**

```
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite ... />
    <testsuite ... />
  </testsuites>
```

The REST-API can handle both, that is the [IBM JUnit schema](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSQ2R2_14.1.0/com.ibm.rsar.analysis.codereview.cobol.doc/topics/cac_useresults_junit.html) and the standard [surefire schema](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report.xsd)

**Now to the problem**; I obviously want to combine those reports into one to avoid having to make a billion requests to the REST-API. However I can't seem to find an automated way. What I've tried so far is

- play around with the [surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html) to merge the XML reports, but no appropriate option seems to exist
- Organise Tests into a (JUnit) test suite, but the output remains an xml report per test
- finding alternative plugins/tools that address this issue, no luck

The only other way I can think of is to write a "merge script" myself, possibly using some sort of XSLT-transformation. But I'd rather not. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to use an external utility for that as surefire seems to not support it.
I've used successfully [junit-merge utility](https://www.npmjs.com/package/junit-merge), which is an NPM package, as you can see for example in [this tutorial](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+Android+Applications+using+Appium+and+JUnit+in+Java).
The usage is pretty straightforward; you just need to specify the output file and the input folder containing the multiple JUnit XML based reports.

```
junit-merge  -o results.xml -d target/surefire-reports/
```